# How to draw a ellipse figure in beamer at desired location? How to put a .eps logo figure at the right bottom corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pstricks

Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{document}

    \title{moumou专题}
    \author{author}
    \institute{moumou@gmail.com}
    \date{2013-08-03}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t]
    \scriptsize
    在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与   BP      的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
    (I)求动点P的轨迹方程;\\
    (II)设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup       \text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
     \begin{pspicture}%[showgrid=true](8,6)
     \psellipse[linecolor=red](4,3)(4,3)
     \pscircle[linecolor=blue](4,3){2}
     \end{pspicture}
     \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t]
    \scriptsize
在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
   (I)求动点P的轨迹方程;\\
   (II)设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup
\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

I can only draw simple figure, but I wonder how to put the figure at some place within a beamer slide.

Here is a picture to describe my question.
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an MWE (i.e. only with things that are necessary for the code to work)? `tikz` should be able to do what you want for the ellipse, if you give it the right coordinates. What methods have you used to insert the eps figure?

Comment: These are two separate questions. Only one problem per question post, please.

Comment: I can only draw ellipse in tikz.I want to place a ellipse some place I want.How can I specify it ?From now on,I will not post such questions which does not have MWE.

Answer (score 1):

You can find solutions to most basic or advanced drawing problems in [PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) and [PSTricks Guide](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf).

Now, for your ellipse, here is my example using [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{moumou专题}
\author{author}
\institute{moumou@gmail.com}
\date{2013-08-03}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\scriptsize 在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.

\begin{enumerate}
\item 求动点P的轨迹方程;
\item 设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw Axes
\draw (0,0) node[below left] {O};
\draw[->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0) node[below] {\(x\)};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[left] {\(y\)};
% Draw Ticks
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2}
\draw (\x,1pt) -- (\x,-1pt) node[below] {\x};
\foreach \y in {-1,1}
\draw (1pt,\y) -- (-1pt,\y) node[left] {\y};
% Draw Ellipse
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and {2/sqrt(3)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Let's check the result to see if it is the intended one:

[image]

**EDIT**: More on alignment. You can use commands

```
{\raggedright ... \par}
{\centering ... \par}
{\raggedleft ... \par}
```

to adjust the horizontal position of the picture.